# Show that the map $f(z) = z^k$ is a open map in the complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I can see that the map $f(z) = z^k$ is an homeomorphism for neighbourhoods around non-zero points not including zero. So I need to check only around neighbourhoods of zero.
Can anyone help me out?

**Edit: As mentioned in the comments, I forgot to mention $k$ here is a positive integer.**

Comment: For  genral result see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736446/open-mapping-principle-complex?rq=1

Comment: Don't know where the downvotes come from, but I think the only problem is that there is no mention of $k$ is a positive integer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix an open set $X\subseteq C$. For each $z\in X$, there is a small radius $r=r_z$ such that the open ball $B_r(z) = \{w\mid |w-z|<r\}$ is completely included in $X$. As you have noticed, for $z\ne 0$, we may choose $r_z$ sufficiently small so that $f(z)=z^k$ restricted to $B_{r_z}$ is a homeomorphism. For $z=0$, $f$ maps $B_r(0)$ to $B_{r^k}(0)$, which is an open set. Therefore, the image of $X$ under $f$ is $\bigcup_{z\in X}f[B_r(z)]$, which is open.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Basically the only problematic point was zero. So if I consider a neighbourhood around zero, I can always get a small enough ball of radius say r, around zero. It will be mapped to a ball of radius r^k in the output space, which is open. Now that the problematic point is removed, the the map restricted to the neighbourhood of other non zero points(obviously not intersecting zero) is a homeomorphism. Thus the map is an open map. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @DwaipayanSharma yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is holomorphic:    $f'(z)=kz^{k-1}.$   And it's nonconstant.  Therefore by the *open mapping theorem* it is open.

Btw it is not a homeomorphism. What about $k$th roots of unity, for instance?

Comment: It is a local homeomorphism around every point $z\neq 0$ (in the source). Also, the Open Mapping Theorem actually follows from the fact that $z\mapsto z^k$ is an open map for every integer $k\geq 1$. The reason is that every nonconstant morphism of Riemann surfaces (e.g., open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$) is locally of the form $z\mapsto z^e$.